# Дублирование сетевого траффика на Linux в утилите iptables

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables

Выполняю учебное задание по сетям. На одном из этапов должно происходить следующее:

1. на компьютер №3 с компьютера №4 приходит пакет, отправленный на адрес, не представленный в сети (например, 123.123.123.123)
2. на компьютере №3 происходит перенаправление принятого пакета на компьютеры №1 и №2 (то есть необходимо провести дублирование и подмену адреса назначения)

[image]

Пробовал делать следующим образом:

```
# дублируем все пакеты, предназначенные для 123.123.123.123, на компьютер №2
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 123.123.123.123 -j TEE --gateway 6.6.1.1
# изменяем поле назначения непродублированных пакетов на адрес компьютера №1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 123.123.123.123 -j DNAT --to-destination 6.6.0.1
```

До компьютера №1 пакеты доходят. Доходят пакеты (дублируются) и до компьютера №2 — но их поля назначения (destination) остаются неизменными (123.123.123.123)

Проблема в том, что не смог найти способа дублирования траффика с проставлением верных полей (в частности назначения)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вставь ДНАТ перед дублированием:

```
# изменяем поле назначения непродублированных пакетов на адрес компьютера №2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 123.123.123.123 -j DNAT --to-destination 6.6.1.1
# дублируем все пакеты, предназначенные для 123.123.123.123, на компьютер №2
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 123.123.123.123 -j TEE --gateway 6.6.1.1
# изменяем поле назначения непродублированных пакетов на адрес компьютера №1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 123.123.123.123 -j DNAT --to-destination 6.6.0.1
```

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, мог бы догадаться. Но теперь почему-то компьютер №3 подменяет порт пакетов с компьютера, на который производилось дублирование, при отсылке их на клиент (компьютер №1). Причём на компьютере №3 не стоят никакие фильтры, которые могли бы это сделать. Всё тестирование производится при помощи netcat. Можете подсказать, в чём могла бы быть проблема?

Comment: А в этом виноват скорее всего контрак. Добавь правило notrack в прероутинг или отключи контрак - проверь, я не уверен, но вроде больше нечему

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо

Comment: 1. А разве не только одно DNAT-правило (первое) будет применено?
2. Дублирование трафика с помощью Mangle точно применимо к разным подсетям (123.123.123.xxx & 6.6.6.y)? К примеру, у меня трафик не дублируется (согласно pcap-файлу)

Comment: @Worker возможно ответ не точен

Comment: @Worker там суть была в том что после tee трафик попадает в прероутинг снова. Первое правило проходит по контраку и попадает во второе